# Assembly loaded from Resources raises Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-assembly, embedded-resource

I am writing a simple application that should create some shortcuts.
For this I use `Interop.IWshRuntimeLibrary` that i add as an Embedded Resource.

On class init I call

```
Assembly.Load(Resources.Interop_IWshRuntimeLibrary);
```

I also tried:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(Resources.Interop_IWshRuntimeLibrary);
```

When I build the application in VisualStudio Output window I see that the assembly is loaded:

> Loaded "Interop.IWshRuntimeLibrary".

But, when I try to use the objects in that assembly it gives me this exception:

> "Could not load file or assembly "Interop.IWshRuntimeLibrary,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null".

Comment: That's normal, Assembly.Load(byte[]) is a very poor way to load assemblies, it has no loading context.  This was fixed a long while ago for interop assemblies, simply set the "Embed Interop Types" to true on the assembly reference.  You no longer have to deploy the assembly.  There's also nothing in that COM component that you cannot do in .NET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not so simple as you think and if Visualstudio says that the reference is loaded it means that the references of the project is loaded during build. It has nothing to do with what you are tring to achieve.

the easiest way is to bind to [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that is called when the resolution of an assembly fails:

```
AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
currentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(MyResolveEventHandler);
```

then:

```
private Assembly MyResolveEventHandler(object sender,ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    Assembly rtn=null;

    //Check for the assembly names that have raised the "AssemblyResolve" event.
    if(args.Name=="YOUR RESOURCE ASSEMBLY NAME")
    {
        //load from resource
        Stream resxStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("YOUR RESOURCE ASSEMBLY NAME");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[resxStream.Length];
        resxStream.Read(buffer, 0, resxStream.Length);
        rtn = Assembly.Load(buffer);
    }
    return rtn;         
}
```