# Why can I not find that assembly?

Tags: c#

```
AppDomainSetup domainSetup = new AppDomainSetup();
// Assign a global path that includes "prinergyweb\bin"
domainSetup.ApplicationBase = @"E:\Projects\IPP\main\prinergyweb";
domainSetup.PrivateBinPath = @"bin";
AppDomain newDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Test", null, domainSetup);
newDomain.Load("A");
```

I make sure that all the paths are correct, but it still throws an exception of "FileNotFound"……Why?
How many reasons do you think can cause this problem? (I've made sure "A.dll" exists).

Other information:

PS1: My disc is compacted

PS2: A.dll isn't a strongly-named dll.

PS3: The path is my PerForce's mapping path.

Comment: Is the `E` drive a local disk? Because e.g. network drive mappings are (mostly) a per-user concept, and so the next question would be, is this code running under *your* account or another one?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? There might actually be another way for wat you are trying.

Comment: You need to check whether "E:\Projects\IPP\main\prinergyweb" exists on the machine where you execute the code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that with `AppDomain.Load` assembly is loaded into both domains.

If the current `AppDomain` object represents application domain A, and the Load method is called from application domain B, the assembly is loaded into both application domains.

The current domain needs to know about those assembly and load them.

If you use the [Assembly Binding Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx) you will see that the newly created domain  loads the assembly from the private bin path, but the current app domain does not.

This is why you get the exception of "File not found".

From [MSDN AppDomain.Load Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36az8x58.aspx)

> This method should be used only to load an assembly into the current
>   application domain. This method is provided as a convenience for
>   interoperability callers who cannot call the static Assembly.Load
>   method. To load assemblies into other application domains, use a
>   method such as CreateInstanceAndUnwrap.

If you want to load some assembly from a different location you should do like I said in this answer: [Assembly loaded from Resources raises Could not load file or assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22556258/assembly-loaded-from-resources-raises-could-not-load-file-or-assembly/22556690#22556690) and handling the [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)